# x-forwarded-for from ELB is coming null

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, tomcat8, elastic-load-balancer

I have an web-application running on Tomcat8 server(A) which calls a rest-service served by another server(B). In between there is ELB load balancer. After successful API calls, after sometime the web-application started throwing exception saying the Rest Call is unsuccessful. On the server B, the access logs shows the ELB Ip address and in place of X-Forwarded-For no value is coming. After restarting the server A it started working fine and X-Forwarded-For value is also coming.

What could be the issue?

Comment: ELB health check requests will not have an x-forwarded-for header.

Comment: It is not health check request as the requested URL for server B is there in access log:

09-Mar-2017 05:59:12.612 AM UTC origin=[10.216.65.124 -] originProtocol=[HTTP/1.1 -] request="GET /search/api/didyoumean?text=sh&categories=STATE&count=5&sort=rank%20desc,search_label_literal%20asc HTTP/1.1" status=400 bytes_sent=- referer="-" user-agent="-" thread_name="null" request_process_time=0 response_time=-